# How to make multiple http call requests (Nodejs )

Tags: php, node.js, wordpress, cron

Need server script for calling many url's synchronously . I tried on nodejs . but wordpress wp-cron.php url gives 500 error's 6 out of 10

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var conn=[];
for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
conn[i]=request('http://www.example.com/site/wp-cron.php', function (error, response, body) {


if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      }
     console.log(response.statusCode);
    });
   }
```

Any suggestion to achieve my objective ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the site has a mechanism of avoiding the span request, so you should controle your request.

Here is a tutorial in my github project of controlling concurrent request, using a tool called "async" : [asyncControle](https://github.com/xie-qianyue/NodeTutorial/tree/master/asyncControle)

If you have any questions, please contact me.